# Unable to compile NME for Android

Tags: android, haxe, nme, hxcpp

Okay, so I'm trying to get an initial build of the NME sample files onto an Android device.

I can build for platforms such as HTML5, Flash and Windows, but I can't get it onto Android - I always get errors back that say:

```
Unable to find a javac compiler;
com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on the classpath.
Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK.
Is is currently set to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7"
```

Okay - obvious enough right?  But I've checked, rechecked, restarted, edited environment variables and made **absolutely** sure that the `JAVA_HOME` variable is actually pointing at the JDK.

Any explanations?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, to answer my own question, I eventually found that there's an `.hxcpp_config.xml` file in my user account (`C:\Users\James\`), and that has an XML node which looked like this:

```
<set name="JAVA_HOME" value="/SDKs//java_jdk" />
```

I've changed it to this:

```
<set name="JAVA_HOME" value="C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_29" />
```

And it works!